# can't login as super user.

Tags: xubuntu, 15.10

I am using Ubuntu 15.10. yesterday I was using it happily but today I got a problem during login as super user.  When enter sudo su -  it ask for ( sudo)  password after giving the password it shows   "cannot execute exit: no such file or directory".  What should I do plzzz it important so help me.

Comment: What is the exact command you ran?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your shell for root is set incorrectly. Please run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

Look for a line containing `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`. Does it look different in your case? Does it maybe say `root:x:0:0:root:/root:exit`?

If so, change the line to match the first one (basically replace 'exit' with '/bin/bash'.